# Rails4 order by column alias in joins group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I want to have the slugs of the categories in descendent order of number of products per category (the category slug for the category witht the most products is first and the ones without products are last)

I Rails 3.2 the query

```
Category.
  joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN products ON products.category_id = categories.id").
  select('count("products"."id") as products_count').
  group("categories.slug").
  order("products_count desc").
  select("categories.slug")
```

worked.
However after upgrading, I get an

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn
```

error, saying that column products_count doesn't exist

```
...and_id = categories.id GROUP BY categories.slug  ORDER BY products_c...
```

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ORDER BY does not recognize aliases.

Quick fix:

```
Category.
  joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN products ON products.category_id = categories.id").
  group("categories.slug").
  order('count("products"."id") desc').
  select("categories.slug")
```

Why did it work before but not after upgrading? I'm not sure, but I guess that it has to do with optimizations (delayed execution) added to ActiveRecord.

Comment: How can you do this query without plain SQL? ActiveRecord sadly still only supports the "normal join". How would you do this query only with built-in AR methods?

Comment: I guess that creating a SQL view would be best in your case. Did you get it to work with that change?

Comment: Is there an ActiveRecord way of creating SQL views?

And if the alias function is not needed at all, couldn't I then not drop the whole `.select(`-line and just end up with `Category.
  joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN products ON products.category_id = categories.id").
  group("categories.slug").
  order('count("products"."id") desc').
  select("categories.slug")` (sorry, the formatting in the comments is not the best)  ?

Comment: Yes, I think you can safely drop the first `select`. As for the views, you can create them using plain SQL in a migration, and then use them just like a table. More info: https://rietta.com/blog/2013/11/28/rails-and-sql-views-for-a-report/

Comment: The query is effectively the same (changes from `SELECT count("products"."id") as products_count, categories.slug FROM "categories" LEFT OUTER JOIN products ON products.brand_id = categories.id GROUP BY categories.slug ORDER BY products_count desc` to `SELECT categories.slug FROM "categories" LEFT OUTER JOIN products ON products.brand_id = categories.id GROUP BY categories.slug ORDER BY count("products"."id") desc` and the results also match.

I'll have a look into the SQL Views for Rails later on and accept your answer for now

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in my project and instead of refactoring the query which wasn't a viable alternative for my scenario I used `order(1)`.

```
Category.
    joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN products ON products.category_id = categories.id").
    select('count("products"."id") as products_count').
    group("categories.slug").
    order(1)
```

It allowed me to use the `SELECT`, `ALIAS` and `GROUP`. I personally don't like "magic numbers" but it was useful in this case.